# Произведение элементов массивов используя плюс на C#

Tags: java, c#, массивы

Подскажите как написать произведение трех элементов массива используя только знак ПЛЮС?

```
int nums[] ={100, 5, 35};
int result = nums[0];

for(int i = 1; i<nums.Length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j <num[i]; j++){
         result += result; 
    }
}
```

Comment: зачем тут два цикла?

Comment: `result += result;` - что это вы тут делаете?

Comment: Нужно произведение или сумма?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**C#**

Сумма

```cs
int[] nums = { 100, 5, 35 };
int result = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
{
    result += nums[i]; 
}

Console.WriteLine(result); // 140
```

Произведение

```cs
int[] nums = { 100, 5, 35 };
int result = nums[0];

for (int i = 1; i < nums.Length; i++)
{
    int a = result;
    for (int j = 1; j < nums[i]; j++)
    {
        result += a;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(result); // 17500
```

Не сработает, если в массиве есть ноль или отрицательное число.

Comment: Кажется, можно пошустрее, если бинарное умножение сделать.

Comment: А если отрицательные числа?

Comment: @Blackmeser спасибо, дополнил

Answer (score 1):

**Java**

```
int nums[] = {100, 5, 35};
int result = nums[0];

for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
     result += nums[i]; 
}

System.out.print(result); // 140
```

Comment: Кажется мы с вами неправильно прочитали вопрос, но я уже исправился.

Comment: кхм.......... )